# Gap between contents

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a news website(in Bangla language)... so I am having a trouble.There is an image below for it[image: gap-problem]

I want to fill the red marked area. How can I do it? The css of news content's is

```
.main-news {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 33.1%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use flex

Comment: yes but what value should I use?

Comment: there's a lot of example on the net, google it 'CSS flex'

Comment: Yes but I can't find the one I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, this problem seems to be quite tough. I would suggest to fill the content vertically first and then horizontally. You should add equal number of blocks to each column. I mean like this:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

So, no horizontal space. However, there will be always some free space vertically since the blocks are not equal. This issue can be solved to certain degree by flexbox justify-content property. Finally, we will get something like this (the wider the screen is, the better):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
      -ms-flex-align: stretch;
          align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
}

.subcontainer {
  -webkit-box-flex: 3;
      -ms-flex: 3 1 33.3%;
          flex: 3 1 33.3%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
      flex-flow: column wrap;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0em 0.5em;
}

.item {
  padding: 0.5em 0em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <div class="item">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</div>
    <div class="item">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</div>
    <div class="item">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</div>
  </div>
    <div class="subcontainer">
    <div class="item">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</div>
    <div class="item">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</div>
    <div class="item">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</div>
  </div>
    <div class="subcontainer">
    <div class="item">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</div>
    <div class="item">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should look quite ok on real monitors and not inside this small sandbox space. For mobile viewports you can always implement corresponding styles.

An alternative to flexboxes can be [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) - check it out. Also I would suggest making the height of blocks equal although in this case the problem is gone naturally :) As far as I know, that's all without resorting to super hacky, messy, JS-involving approaches. Maybe others will come up with better solutions though.

**PS** check out this [css grid example](http://labs.jensimmons.com/2017/01-009D.html). **Seems to be similar to what you want to achieve**, although the [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid) for css grid is not full yet.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting a specific size to your image and height to your news block

```
 .main-news {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 33.1%;
    height: 200px;    // new code
    overflow: hidden; // new code
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
}
.main-news img{// new code
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: While this approach is definitely more cross-browser alternative in some cases to flexboxes and simpler, I would like to mention that the blocks might not have the same height (which is the case) and the empty space will persist. So, I guess the flexboxes is the way to go.

Comment: i've already put a height and width of img. But I don't want to display every news-block on the same size

Answer (score 0):

> Flex is also a good approch see this for reference,
>   Click [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

OR,

> You can give min-height instead of height it may be solve your issue,
>   but it takes all the blocks same height

```
.main-news {
   vertical-align: top;
   margin-top: 0;
   width: 33.1%;
   min-height: 600px;
   overflow: auto;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   display: inline-block;
}
```